# What is the cartesian product of a nonempty set and an empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\emptyset$ and $B=[a,b]$ where $R⊃A,B$

What is $A \times B $ where $\times$ denotes the cartesian product?

How can we explain this $A\times B$ in $R^2$, what does it look like?

Comment: $A\times B = \emptyset$

Comment: Okay, is $\emptyset$ considered bounded btw?

Comment: @Xenidia Can you put all the elements of $\;\emptyset\;$ into a sphere of radius $\;0.288823762\;$ centered at...whatever you want?

Comment: Your question about $\emptyset$ being bounded should be asked in a separate question.

Comment: @Xenidia, Is it meaningful to ask if $\emptyset$ is bounded? Indeed as DonAntonion said, you can bound it with a ball of radius $0.288823762$ centered at *whatever you want*. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\times B$ is the set of all elements which can be written as pairs $(a,b)$ where $a$ is an element of $A$ and $b$ is an element of $B$.  You should know what it means that $b$ is an element of $B$, so let's focus on the first part.  $a$ has to be an element of $A$, but $A$ has no elements, so there are no possibilities for $a$.  Therefore, there are no possible $(a,b)$'s and $A\times B$ is empty.

Since the set is empty, there's nothing to draw in $\mathbb{R}^2$.